# pyteomics: calculate mass from a file containing the sequence of several proteins

Tags: python

I want to calculate the mass for every protein of my file.

My code so far:

```
from pyteomics import mass
 with open('file.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
             mass.calculate_mass(line)
```

When I replace the `mass.calculate_mass` with `print(line)` all the lines are correctly printed. But with `mass.calculate_mass(line)` come several error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/michaela/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyteomics/parser.py", line 275, in parse
    n, body, c = re.match(_modX_sequence, sequence).groups() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/michaela/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyteomics/mass/mass.py", line 304, in __init__
    self._from_sequence(args[0], aa_comp)   File "/home/michaela/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyteomics/mass/mass.py", line 200, in _from_sequence
    show_unmodified_termini=True)   File "/home/michaela/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyteomics/parser.py", line 277, in parse
    raise PyteomicsError('Not a valid modX sequence: ' + sequence) pyteomics.auxiliary.PyteomicsError: Pyteomics error, message: "Not a valid modX sequence: 'MELNLTQLPLVHITFCGRPAVSIGVVNLVGLFGSTDYVLLQRIGSQGQTALRKGDGGGRHSKDSRDSSLDSLEIENRVRSSNMKLCRNTGLPVGCYNVVEGGIYDVVRYSDLRKGKVKGMDFATLNRHSDGRPKTRRGCRSRRKRRRDGTVENAAQSTPSDTVSSSFKQPSTPVPTDPSGTSGGTNGVSQRAKVVRAAQPSERKAHQKATKVSQTSKQTGGKEAPAVDEKNSNGTKVERTRTTKPRAPGIPKERPPRVGKEKVQQLKPVAEAAPQHAPSRSPSPRQANSNFAAVVLTASDLRSCDLGSSLSNVSVCTDKAETQMTPTTGPVTTSMQLNKSKHVPSSTGRTAAQDNGAKKTPQVATPVGESANAKKQQDVVDVDNALLVGHGSSSNGKKEGGSTGLANVRTDHSRDVVDRRAAAAPSNSIVECPCAPDAASPELGFVTVESALSRDFSLGSSLASSADSVY'\n"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/michaela/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyteomics/mass/mass.py", line 307, in __init__
    self._from_formula(args[0], mass_data)   File "/home/michaela/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyteomics/mass/mass.py", line 205, in _from_formula
    raise PyteomicsError('Invalid formula: ' + formula) pyteomics.auxiliary.PyteomicsError: Pyteomics error, message: "Invalid formula: 'MELNLTQLPLVHITFCGRPAVSIGVVNLVGLFGSTDYVLLQRIGSQGQTALRKGDGGGRHSKDSRDSSLDSLEIENRVRSSNMKLCRNTGLPVGCYNVVEGGIYDVVRYSDLRKGKVKGMDFATLNRHSDGRPKTRRGCRSRRKRRRDGTVENAAQSTPSDTVSSSFKQPSTPVPTDPSGTSGGTNGVSQRAKVVRAAQPSERKAHQKATKVSQTSKQTGGKEAPAVDEKNSNGTKVERTRTTKPRAPGIPKERPPRVGKEKVQQLKPVAEAAPQHAPSRSPSPRQANSNFAAVVLTASDLRSCDLGSSLSNVSVCTDKAETQMTPTTGPVTTSMQLNKSKHVPSSTGRTAAQDNGAKKTPQVATPVGESANAKKQQDVVDVDNALLVGHGSSSNGKKEGGSTGLANVRTDHSRDVVDRRAAAAPSNSIVECPCAPDAASPELGFVTVESALSRDFSLGSSLASSADSVY'\n"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/michaela/calculatemass.py", line 5, in <module>
    mass.calculate_mass(line)   File "/home/michaela/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyteomics/mass/mass.py", line 499, in calculate_mass
    else Composition(*args, **kwargs))   File "/home/michaela/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyteomics/mass/mass.py", line 312, in __init__
    'formula'.format(args[0])) pyteomics.auxiliary.PyteomicsError: Pyteomics error, message: 'Could not create a Composition object from string: "\'MELNLTQLPLVHITFCGRPAVSIGVVNLVGLFGSTDYVLLQRIGSQGQTALRKGDGGGRHSKDSRDSSLDSLEIENRVRSSNMKLCRNTGLPVGCYNVVEGGIYDVVRYSDLRKGKVKGMDFATLNRHSDGRPKTRRGCRSRRKRRRDGTVENAAQSTPSDTVSSSFKQPSTPVPTDPSGTSGGTNGVSQRAKVVRAAQPSERKAHQKATKVSQTSKQTGGKEAPAVDEKNSNGTKVERTRTTKPRAPGIPKERPPRVGKEKVQQLKPVAEAAPQHAPSRSPSPRQANSNFAAVVLTASDLRSCDLGSSLSNVSVCTDKAETQMTPTTGPVTTSMQLNKSKHVPSSTGRTAAQDNGAKKTPQVATPVGESANAKKQQDVVDVDNALLVGHGSSSNGKKEGGSTGLANVRTDHSRDVVDRRAAAAPSNSIVECPCAPDAASPELGFVTVESALSRDFSLGSSLASSADSVY\'\n": not a valid sequence or formula'
```

my file looks like this:

```
'MELNLTQLPLVHITFCGRPAVSIGVVNLVGLFGSTDYVLLQRIGSQGQTALRKGDGGGRHSKDSRDSSLDSLEIENRVRSSNMKLCRNTGLPVGCYNVVEGGIYDVVRYSDLRKGKVKGMDFATLNRHSDGRPKTRRGCRSRRKRRRDGTVENAAQSTPSDTVSSSFKQPSTPVPTDPSGTSGGTNGVSQRAKVVRAAQPSERKAHQKATKVSQTSKQTGGKEAPAVDEKNSNGTKVERTRTTKPRAPGIPKERPPRVGKEKVQQLKPVAEAAPQHAPSRSPSPRQANSNFAAVVLTASDLRSCDLGSSLSNVSVCTDKAETQMTPTTGPVTTSMQLNKSKHVPSSTGRTAAQDNGAKKTPQVATPVGESANAKKQQDVVDVDNALLVGHGSSSNGKKEGGSTGLANVRTDHSRDVVDRRAAAAPSNSIVECPCAPDAASPELGFVTVESALSRDFSLGSSLASSADSVY'
```

I also tried it with

sequence='MELNLTQLPLVHITFCGRPAVSIGVVNLVGLFGSTDYVLLQRIGSQGQTALRKGDGGGRHSKDSRDSSLDSLEIENRVRSSNMKLCRNTGLPVGCYNVVEGGIYDVVRYSDLRKGKVKGMDFATLNRHSDGRPKTRRGCRSRRKRRRDGTVENAAQSTPSDTVSSSFKQPSTPVPTDPSGTSGGTNGVSQRAKVVRAAQPSERKAHQKATKVSQTSKQTGGKEAPAVDEKNSNGTKVERTRTTKPRAPGIPKERPPRVGKEKVQQLKPVAEAAPQHAPSRSPSPRQANSNFAAVVLTASDLRSCDLGSSLSNVSVCTDKAETQMTPTTGPVTTSMQLNKSKHVPSSTGRTAAQDNGAKKTPQVATPVGESANAKKQQDVVDVDNALLVGHGSSSNGKKEGGSTGLANVRTDHSRDVVDRRAAAAPSNSIVECPCAPDAASPELGFVTVESALSRDFSLGSSLASSADSVY'

There are no empty lines in my file. 
If I try the same in the shell, it works:

```
mass.calculate_mass('MELNLTQLPLVHITFCGRPAVSIGVVNLVGLFGSTDYVLLQRIGSQGQTALRKGDGGGRHSKDSRDSSLDSLEIENRVRSSNMKLCRNTGLPVGCYNVVEGGIYDVVRYSDLRKGKVKGMDFATLNRHSDGRPKTRRGCRSRRKRRRDGTVENAAQSTPSDTVSSSFKQPSTPVPTDPSGTSGGTNGVSQRAKVVRAAQPSERKAHQKATKVSQTSKQTGGKEAPAVDEKNSNGTKVERTRTTKPRAPGIPKERPPRVGKEKVQQLKPVAEAAPQHAPSRSPSPRQANSNFAAVVLTASDLRSCDLGSSLSNVSVCTDKAETQMTPTTGPVTTSMQLNKSKHVPSSTGRTAAQDNGAKKTPQVATPVGESANAKKQQDVVDVDNALLVGHGSSSNGKKEGGSTGLANVRTDHSRDVVDRRAAAAPSNSIVECPCAPDAASPELGFVTVESALSRDFSLGSSLASSADSVY')
```

49589.2790365072

I also tried `mass.calculate_mass(str(line))` but that did not help.

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Greetings from the review queue!  I don't know enough about the package you're using to help much, but you may want to flag more than just  `python` if you want help with specific packages.  Just as a basic troubleshooting tip, make sure your text file doesn't have any empty lines.  It looks like the method you called is trying to process an empty string.

Comment: I actually wanted to make a flag for the package pyteomics but I was not allowed because there doesn't exist such a flag yet...

Comment: If there's no flag for it, it's probably not a very well-known package. You probably should give a bit more background in your question, instead of assuming anyone searching the `python` tag will know what your package does.  Also I'm pretty sure your error trace is incomplete.  Try to put the full trace in your question so people can see what the interpreter is telling you.

Comment: Also, are you sure your text file doesn't have an empty line somewhere?

Comment: Hi, I am the author of pyteomics so I'll be glad to help. However, there is currently not enough information in your question. Clearly there are problematic lines in your file but you are not showing it. So, you can improve your question (and help us help you) by creating a minimal example of the input file that demonstrates the problem and [edit]ing it into the question.

Comment: Please post solutions as answers, not as updates to your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your file contains quotes (`'`). These are interpreted as part of the sequence and break the parser.
If you just put sequences in your file without any additional characters, it should work fine:

```
MELNLTQLPLVHITFCGRPAVSIGVVNLVGLFGSTDYVLLQRIGSQGQTALRKGDGGGRHSKDSRDSSLDSLEIENRVRSSNMKLCRNTGLPVGCYNVVEGGIYDVVRYSDLRKGKVKGMDFATLNRHSDGRPKTRRGCRSRRKRRRDGTVENAAQSTPSDTVSSSFKQPSTPVPTDPSGTSGGTNGVSQRAKVVRAAQPSERKAHQKATKVSQTSKQTGGKEAPAVDEKNSNGTKVERTRTTKPRAPGIPKERPPRVGKEKVQQLKPVAEAAPQHAPSRSPSPRQANSNFAAVVLTASDLRSCDLGSSLSNVSVCTDKAETQMTPTTGPVTTSMQLNKSKHVPSSTGRTAAQDNGAKKTPQVATPVGESANAKKQQDVVDVDNALLVGHGSSSNGKKEGGSTGLANVRTDHSRDVVDRRAAAAPSNSIVECPCAPDAASPELGFVTVESALSRDFSLGSSLASSADSVY
```

Note that the end-of-line characters don't cause any problems, although that is not documented.

Comment: If i do it without the quotes the error messages disappear but the output in the shell is only: >>>
I also tried it in the terminal and saved it into a file. But the file was empty...

Comment: @user8252931 your code doesn't call print(), so nothing is printed. Try calling print(mass.calculate_mass(line)) inside the loop. In Python terminal you don't need print() if you evaluate a single expression, but with a loop it doesn't work.

Comment: that was it! Thanks!

Comment: @user8252931 you can accept the answer by clicking on the tick to the left of it to mark your question as solved.

Comment: I already did that but it is not shown because I am new and my reputation is below 15...

Comment: @user8252931 15 reputation is needed to upvote, but you can still accept. There is supposed to be a tick below the voting buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an issue with "EOL" char (`'\n'`). Try:

```
mass.calculate_mass(line.strip())
```

Does it work?

`line.strip()` removes leading/trailing white spaces from your line. See [`strip()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm) for more information.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work, the error message was the same

Answer (score 0):

It worked after changing the file to:

> MELNLTQLPLVHITFCGRPAVSIGVVNLVGLFGSTDYVLLQRIGSQGQTALRKGDGGGRHSKDSRDSSLDSLEIENRVRSSNMKLCRNTGLPVGCYNVVEGGIYDVVRYSDLRKGKVKGMDFATLNRHSDGRPKTRRGCRSRRKRRRDGTVENAAQSTPSDTVSSSFKQPSTPVPTDPSGTSGGTNGVSQRAKVVRAAQPSERKAHQKATKVSQTSKQTGGKEAPAVDEKNSNGTKVERTRTTKPRAPGIPKERPPRVGKEKVQQLKPVAEAAPQHAPSRSPSPRQANSNFAAVVLTASDLRSCDLGSSLSNVSVCTDKAETQMTPTTGPVTTSMQLNKSKHVPSSTGRTAAQDNGAKKTPQVATPVGESANAKKQQDVVDVDNALLVGHGSSSNGKKEGGSTGLANVRTDHSRDVVDRRAAAAPSNSIVECPCAPDAASPELGFVTVESALSRDFSLGSSLASSADSVY
>   (without sequence = or quotes)

and by changing the code to:

```
from pyteomics import mass
```

`with open('file.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
             print(mass.calculate_mass(line))`